# Is there an R port of the testing software QuickCheck?

Tags: r, perl, testing, quickcheck, testthat

Now that I find myself spending so much time programming in R, I really want to get back to automated testing (which I learned to do by habit in Perl). Besides being user-friendly, I would also be particularly interested in being able to generate random inputs for tests like Perl's [`Test::LectroTest`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::LectroTest) or Haskell's [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck). Is there anything similar for `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the R package [`quickcheck` on GitHub](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck).

Like `Test::LectroTest`, the R package `quickcheck` is a port of [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck), which Koen Claessen and John Hughes wrote for Haskell.

In addition to QuickCheck features, `quickcheck` also gives a nod to Hadley Wickam's popular [`testthat`](https://github.com/hadley/testthat) R package, by intentionally incorporating his "expectation" functions (which they call "assertions"). In addition to numerical and string tests are tests for failures and warnings, etc.

Here is a simple example using it:

```
library(quickcheck)

my_square <- function(x){x^2}        # the function to test

test( function(x = rinteger())  min(my_square(x)) >= 0 )
# Pass  function (x = rinteger())  
#  min(my_square(x)) >= 0 
# [1] TRUE

test( function(x = rdouble())
      all.equal(
                my_square(x),
                x^2
      )
)
# Pass  function (x = rdouble())  
#  all.equal(my_square(x), x^2) 
# [1] TRUE
```

The first test ensures that anything generated by `my_square` is positive. The second test actually replicates the functionality of `my_square` and checks every output to make sure it is correct.

Note that `rinteger()` produces a vector of any length consisting of integer values. Other randomly generated input data can be produced using functions like `rcharacter`, `rdouble`, and `rmatrix`.

---

Comment: quickcheck dev here. Feel free to reach out for feedback, bugs etc.  Assertion is the normal CS terminology for these things. Expectation is a loaded term in statistics and so there was no question in my mind we should stick with established terminology.